# Not able to generate dynamic short link with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am able to generate the long link but no luck with creating a short link. onComplete event doesn't get fired at all.

```
DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
    .setLink(Uri.parse(link))
    .setDynamicLinkDomain("richdad.page.link")
    .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("in.geekunit.richdad").build())
    .buildDynamicLink();

General.Show(MainActivity.this, "Long link " + dynamicLink.getUri().toString());

FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
    .setLongLink(dynamicLink.getUri())
    .buildShortDynamicLink().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task)
{
    General.Show(MainActivity.this, "onComplete");
    if (task.isSuccessful())
    {
        mInvitationUrl = task.getResult().getShortLink();
        General.Show(MainActivity.this, mInvitationUrl.toString());
    }
    else
    {
        General.Show(MainActivity.this, "Error");
    }
}
});
```

Tried with generating short link directly as well, I see the same issue.

**This is working fine on 2 devices I tried out of 4.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an issue with FDL aSDK 16.1.0 & old PlayService. I suggest:
- create short link from long link.
- or, wait for a newer FDL aSDK (containing the fix).

Working on some devices suggest those devices have differing PlayService version.

Hope this helps.